# Creating connection pool with tns alias

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, connection-pooling, tns

Has anyone tried creating a WebLogic JDBC connection pool using a TNS Alias instead of a full blown connection string using server:port,db information in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt supported. Not a feature supported out of box on the server